# How do select menus work in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I build them?
Do I add columns in my migration to make the options?
Do I just create actions/methods in my controllers/models?

I'm extremely confused over this (maybe it's due to sleep deprivation of just thinking to hard on it). Could someone point me in the right direction or provide some nice resources with links.

**How do select menus work in Rails??**

---

***More info + Example***
I know how to get them displayed already. I'm just a little confused as to how to use them. For an example, let's say I have 3 options in my select menu "Relationship status"{options = single, married, engaged}. How would I get these to hold a value & send information to my app?
Do I create migrations for single, married, & engaged? Then how can I store this information in my app? Do i make them booleans?

Comment: Select menus are a feature of HTML, not Rails. Rails does include a number of helpers for generating them easily, though.

Comment: When editing a post, please consider whether you're completely changing the scope of the question. From these change logs, it's obvious that the original post has been modified in _very material_ ways, such that some of the posted answers do not correspond to your question as it currently stands: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17017578/revisions

Comment: The question & what's above the part where it says "More info + Example" has never changed. Now what's below I added more info to help explain what I was trying to ask because I felt I did not explain it well enough (what's below "More info + Example"). The question has never changed, nor has anything above "More info + Example" -- "How do select menus work in Rails??" But _thank you_ for being pedantic & fastidious ;) @zeantsoi (doesn't seem like it was modified in _"very material ways"_ http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17017578/revisions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some resource could help you:

1. http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select
2. http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag
3. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html

**Updated**

ok, try this:

```
<%= select_tag "favorite_color", '<option value="red">Red</option><option value="green">Green</option><option value="blue">Blue</option>'.html_safe %>
```

after submitting your form to a action inside your controller, you can get it as `params`.

Comment: I know how to get them displayed already. I'm just a little confused as to how to use them. For an example, I would like to have 3 options in my select menu "Favorite Color"{options = blue, red, yellow}. How would I get these to hold a value & send information to my app? @rony36

Comment: ok, I have updated my answer, please check it. Say, your form for `@color`. So, can can get it like this: `params[:color][:favorite_color]`

Comment: See, that's the thing. I know exactly how to display, but I don't know how they work in terms of storing the information & what underlies the different options (if that made sense). Do I make them booleans? Strings? @rony36

Comment: oh sorry I misunderstood that. My answer updated again. There I putted `value=` tag inside `<option>`, that value would be save. And you can get it as `string`.

Comment: Ahh, so you can make it a string? Do you think it would be smart to use booleans? For an example, relationship status options: "Single, married, or engaged" since each are booleans, unselected ones are false & selecting one will make it true @rony36

Comment: @rony36, `.html_safe` should __follow__ the single quote, not __precede__ it.

Comment: @zeantsoi: ahh, sorry for mistake, just updated my answer. btw, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass in static options to your select menu, you can simply pass in the respective markup and have Rails interpolated it as `html_safe`:

```
<%= select_tag 'Favorite Color', '<option>Blue</option><option>Red</option><option>Yellow</option>'.html_safe %>
```

EDIT:

If you're looking to make the color options dynamic and model based, then yes, you'll probably need to create some migrations:

```
# in console
rails g model color user_id:integer name:string
rake db:migrate

# create some colors in the Rails console
rails console
Color.create(name: 'blue')
Color.create(name: 'red')
Color.create(name: 'yellow')
```

You don't say what model you're trying to assign `favorite_color` to, but let's assume it's a model for `User`. Since users can only have one favorite color, you'll set up a `has_one` relationship:

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :color
end

# app/models/color.rb
class Color < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Your controller actions should look something like this:

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @user = User.new
    end

    def create
        @user = User.new(params[:user])
        if @user.save
            # do something
        else 
            # do something else
        end
    end
end
```

Finally, your view should be something akin to the following:

```
# app/views/users/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
    <!-- whatever other `user` inputs you have -->
    <%= f.collection_select :color, Color.all, :id, :name %>

    <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: See, that's the thing. I know exactly how to display, but I don't know how they work in terms of storing the information & what underlies the different options (if that made sense). Do I make them booleans? Strings? @zeantsoi

Comment: Whether "Single, married, or engaged" should be booleans is a totally different question from what was originally posited (for the record: no, they should not). If this post satisfactorily answered your question regarding colors, then I would suggest that you accept it as correct and ask your boolean question in a separate post.

Comment: It wasn't about "colors" but about how select menus in rails work (see question). But thank you for your help

Comment: This is ridiculous. You've continually edited your original post in ways that completely change the scope of your question. And your post is _indeed_ about "colors"... you went as far as to list the specific colors you wanted to include, but of course you've edited them out of your post. And now, you're asking about "relationship status". So no, you're not asking about how things works in general – you're asking about how something works in specific. If you're going to utilize and contribute to SO on an ongoing basis, you have a lot to learn about how this place works.